# Amazon lex is not giving a successful response for values other than the defined slot values

Tags: amazon-lex

I have a custom slot type defined and I have put slot values like 32, 34, 36, 38, small, large. I have set the Slot Resolution to 'Expand Values'. I have an utterance 'Show me option 32'.
I have assigned the slots to the utterances. I save the intent and build the bot. When I try to test the bot, it gives a success response only to the values mentioned in slot type. If I type, 'Show me option 34' or 'show me option 38' or 'show me option small', it responds with a success json. If I give any other number other than specified slot values, the dialog state shows ElicitIntent and bot responds saying 'Sorry, can you please repeat that?'. Eg: 'Show me option 41'

Why is lex not identifying[image] other numbers? Am I missing anything?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k50E1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that a slot is required in your intent. In aws-lex you entered values in expand values, it will consider any number type like.

now "show me 41" also it will work .after slot is marked as required. If you won't mark as required it will directly fulfill the intent. If you make it required it will elicit the slot and then it will search for respective slot.